# what does n_round means in Xgboost

Tags: r, python, boosting

I am using xgboost recently and here are my questions

(1) When I applied xgboost both on R and Python, I found that there is a parameter called "n_round" in R, but I can't find this parameter in Python xgbRegressor(). What this n_round means? Does it equals to the n_estimators we set up?

(2)By this website 
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html
I found that it used num_round, which seem to be n_round in R.

`import xbgoost as xgb
xgb.train(num_round = 2)`

But when in xgbClassifier, why there is no num_round parameter ?

`from xgboost import xgbClassifier
model = xgbClassifier()
model.fit(train)`

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked exactly the same question for R's implementation of xgboost. `n_rounds` is the equivalence of `n_estimators` in python.

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2031

The author of the package needs to fix this confusing discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
But there is a parameter in R, called "num_parallel_tree "
Do you know what does that means?
for example, if we set n_rounds = 100, num_paralle_tree = 1.
How many trees will we have in final result?

Comment: @jimmy15923 The doc says it's experimental for comparing with RF. I'd leave it at 1.